# ストーキング誹謗行為の　可能性に付いて、

Tags: 討議

憶測の　域を、
出ない　話しで、
申し訳ないですが。
"

どうやら、

私の　投稿に対して、
ストーキング行為を　行い、

内容の　如何に、
関わらず、

評価を　下げて、
回った　ものが、
いた、

と　思われます。
"

さて、

此を　受けて、
討議を　要請します。
"

其の前に、

本案件で　扱うものの、
前提条件に付いてですが。
"

其れは、

前述に　拘わらず、
こうした　事態が、
事実　発生する、
場合、

です。
"

では、

此処で　ご意見を、
募ります。
"

こうした、

ストーキング誹謗行為は、
容認されるべき　事でしょうか？
"

其れとも、

ストーキング誹謗行為は　否定され、
再発防止策を　講じ、

未然に　防止しておく、
べきでしょうか？
"

一方、

実行者には　其れなりの、
制裁を、

加える　べきでしょうか？
"

他方、

ストーキング誹謗を　受けたと、
おぼしき　ものへは、

救済措置が　加えられる、
べきでしょうか？
"

如何でしょうか、

以上　3点、
ご意見を　お待ちして、
おります。

Comment: 一定の品質を保った投稿であるのに不当なモデレーションがあったとしたら、自然とプラスもされていきますので、気にする必要は無いです。良い投稿をお待ちしています。

Comment: 私がマイナスをつけたわけではないですが、いくつか回答を拝見させてもらって思ったことは質問者様の前提を無視していることが見受けられますね。回答の方にもコメントさせていただきました。質問者の前提を崩すならば質問のコメントで追加質問や確認をしたほうがいいと思います。まだ信用度が低いのでコメントできないかもしれないですが、いくつか質問や回答を繰り返すことで信用度はたまっていきます。ぜひ挑戦してみてください。

Comment: htb様へ、

ご発言は　ストーキング容認と、
とらえられて　構わない、
ものでしょうか？
"

其れとも、

そうした　動向は、
否定される　ものでしょうか？

Comment: keitaro_so様へ、
"

失礼ながら　当該は、

確かに、
其の　発端としては、
私への　評価では、
ありましたが。
"

反面として、

其の　本題としては、
一般的な、
現在、及び　未来に、
起こりうる、

ストーキング犯罪に付いてです。
"

ですので、

何とも　口幅ったくは、
あるのですが、

再度　ご発言趣旨を、
確認　頂ければ、
幸いかと　存じます、

如何でしょうか？

Answer (score 6):

スタック・オーバーフローには行動規範があります。コミュニティのメンバーは、この規範を尊重した行動をすることが望まれています。ご質問の 3 点については、この行動規範の内容が答えになっているでしょう: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct

一方で、同時に、スタック・オーバーフローには投票の機能があり、"良い" 投稿が目立つようになっています。nouble さんのご回答を拝見したところ、質問の内容に答えていない回答がいくつか見受けられるようでした。今いくつか入っているマイナス投票のいくつかは、ご投稿のそのような側面などから評価が入っているのではないかと思います。私見ですが、いわゆるストーキングのようなものでは無さそうです。

このような状況を改善するためには、ご自身の回答をより改善できないか検討してみてください。たとえばヘルプセンターの[「良い回答を書くには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)には「質問に回答する」ことがヒントのひとつとして紹介されています。より良い回答が投稿に対しては、プラス投票が入ることでしょう。

他に、ヘルプセンター[「スパム発信者にならないようにどうすればいいですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)から回答のコツを引用いたします。

> - **質問者の問題を解決する**　適切な回答は少なくとも質問者の問題を解決します。もし自分ではいい回答ができないと思ったら、他の質問に回答した方がいいかもしれません。
> - **長く使える回答を目指す**　単に質問者の問題を解決するだけではなく、将来その問題を検索する人のためにもなるような回答ができるとベストです。例えば、なぜその解決策が適切なのか、どのようにして解決するのかを説明してください。理由が示されていれば、似たような問題にも適用できるはずです。
> - **質の低い質問を避ける**　いい回答であっても質問の質が低いと、回答がも低質に見えることがあります。ここでは何がオントピックなのかも参考にしてください。

最後に、もし良い回答を投稿したはずなのにプラス投票されない場合の相談先をいくつか挙げておきます。ただし、完璧な回答というものは難しく、かなり注意深く書いた回答も誰かにとってはマイナスな回答になってしまいうることはご承知おきください。多少のマイナス投票は気にしないで大丈夫です。時間が経つにつれ、より多くのプラス投票によって打ち消されるでしょうから。

- [誰かが何か悪いことをしているのを見つけたら？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)
- [迷惑行為を受けた場合、どうすればよい？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/harassment)

Comment: 本当に、

其れだけで　構わないと、
真剣に　感じて、
おられますが？
"

現在、未来、

現実に　ハラスメント行為が、
執行された　フシが、
見られるのらば、

其れでは　　足りない、
事を、
意味して　いませんか？
"

もし、

画に　描いた、
餅化しているならば、

再考を　求めて、
当然かと　思います。
"

所で、

問題解決の　プロフェショナル部門たる、
品質管理を　研究した、
学問では、

其の　基礎として、
問題発掘と、対策において、

4Mを　一つとして、
提唱しています。
"

4Mとは、

マン、マシン、マテリアル、メソッド、
の　頭文字Mで、

其の　意図を、
紐解くならば。
"

例として、

「個人に　改善を、
押し付けて、
終いとする、」
よりも、

同コストを　多方面に、
分散させ、
アプローチを、
施す　方が、
高工率を　得られる、
事を、
暗示する　ものです。

Comment: 此は、

問題影響量を　Gとおき、
対策量を　Fとおいて、
問題改善効果を　G/Fと、
みる　時に、

Fが　肥大するに、
連れても、

G/Fは　必ずしも、
F変異とは　同率には、
反応しなくなり、

詰まりは　効果が、
薄れる　実態を、
明示的に　示す、
もので。
"

此れは、

感覚的に　理解出来るものと、
思います。
"

いいかえれば、

学術的にも　先筆通りに、
・一方策に　頼らず、
　一方面に　過重を、
　寄らさず、

　他方面への　アプローチ可能性を、
　常に　模索し、
　施策に　反映させ続ける、
　方が、

　効果が　期待出来る。
"

そうした事を、

説明し終えている　ものと、
思われます。
"

さて、

本当に、
能動的な　随時の、
マシンによる　調査や、
異常行動の　レポート機能、
等　なくして、
防ぎきれるのでしょうか？
十分なのでしょうか？
"

其れとも、

被害者は、
やられ放題、虐められ放題で、
今後は　被害発生が、
実質的には　推奨される、
べきでしょうか？

如何でしょうか。

Comment: 改めまして、nekketsuuu様、ご意見の　投稿に、感謝　致します。

Answer (score 2):

> ストーキング誹謗行為は、容認されるべき事でしょうか？

そのような行為は道義的に容認されるべきではないと思います。たとえ不正行為が後で無効化されるとしても、それは行為自体を正当化しません。スタック・オーバーフローでは、そのような短時間での大量の投票は不正投票と呼ばれる場合があります。

---

> ストーキング誹謗行為は否定され、再発防止策を講じ、未然に防止しておくべきでしょうか？

現状のスタック・オーバーフローのシステムでは、ユーザによる不正投票は自動的に検知され、場合によってはモデレータやサイト開発者がそれらの投票について調査を実施します。投票に不正があったと見なされると、それらの不正な投票はすべて無効化されます。これはヘルプセンターの[信用度ページで、「連続投票が取り消されました」 で信用度が変更されているのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)に記載されています。

> ### 「連続賛成投票が取り消されました」 または「連続反対投票が取り消されました」 とはどういう意味ですか？
>
> 票が無効化されると、その票による信用度の獲得または喪失は取り消され、その結果受領者の信用度履歴に「連続賛成投票が取り消されました」または「連続反対投票が取り消されました」というラベルの記録が残ります。

---

> 一方、実行者には其れなりの制裁を加えるべきでしょうか？

当該不正行為についてモデレータへ通報すると（またはモデレータが当該行為を確認すると）、不正な操作を行ったユーザは不正の内容によって警告、アカウントの凍結や削除などの措置を受ける場合があります。具体的には、[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)に書かれています。

> ### 施行
>
> 私たちはあなたの報告を真摯に受け止めます。誠意を持って行動規範を遵守していない人は、モデレーションチームが適切と考える判断にゆだねられることになります。モデレーターが一般的に容認できない行為を処理する方法は次の通りです :
>
> 1. **警告**
>    初めての不正行為の場合、モデレーターが問題のコンテンツを削除し警告を送信します。ほとんどの問題がここで解決されます。
> 2. **アカウント停止**
>    ハラスメントや偏見、威嚇などを含む不正行為が繰り返された場合、モデレーションチームはユーザーアカウントの一時停止（日数は違反に応じて一日以上）を行います。
> 3. **アカウント削除**
>    非常にまれなケースでは、モデレーションチームがコミュニティにとって有害で破壊的な行動パターンを示すユーザーを除名します。

---

> 他方、ストーキング誹謗を受けたとおぼしきものへは、救済措置が加えられるべきでしょうか？

ヘルプセンターの記事を読む限り、不正行為によって失った信用度の回復以外には、現時点で明らかになっている救済措置はありません<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)</sup>。これは憶測になりますが、救済措置は通報を受けた後にモデレータがケースバイケースで決めることもあると思います。

Comment: どういう救済措置を想定なさっているのかが分からないのですが、たとえばマイナス投票が解除されて戻ってきた分より追加で余計に信用度が加算されたりはしません。バッジを与えたりもできません。何かしら見返りのようなものは基本的には無いと考えていただいて大丈夫なはず……です。せいぜいできるとして、何かしら対応が為されたことをチャット等で伝える程度です。

Comment: supa様、ご意見の　投稿に、感謝　致します。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、

ご質問を　承りました。
"1/2

〉どういう救済措置を想定なさっているのか

特に　想定は、
していません。
"

只々、

正道にも、叙情にも、
沿う　内容が、
得られれば、
と、

思う　次第です。
"

〉追加で余計に信用度が加算されたりは

其れは、

唯の　不正への、
請求であって
救済の　範疇外と、
思いますし。
"

私が、

求めた　範疇外でも、
あります。
"

さりとて、

サイト総意としての、
被害者に対する　サイト全員からの、
謝罪として、

皆様か　必要と、
感じられ、
合意形成に　至られるならば。

私は、

其の　動向を、
覗い、

必要に、応じて、
折々に　意見を、
述べるだけ、
と、

今は　考えて、
おります。
"


まぁ、

何れにしても　未来の、
事、
ケセラセラかも　知れませんがね。

Comment: 2/2

〉バッジを与えたりもできません。

不正行為により、
不当に　剥奪された、
何某かも、

「回復に　伴っては、
同時に、

公正な　範囲内では、
回復されても、
不当ではない、」
と、

思いますが　如何でしょうか？
"

〉チャット等で伝える程度

其の事は、

罪を課すか？
にも、

関わる　事だと、
考えます。
"

紐解けば、

罪を　課す、
必要が、
本当に　あるのか、

罪で　本当に、
諫め得るのか、

罪とは　集団における、
公利維持のための、
乳母捨て山的　個人阻害攻撃の、
側面は　ないのか、
等の、

問題が　示唆されます。
"

詰まりは、

此は　旬然とした、
社会科学的問題であり、

一個人たる　私か、
「どうこういえる　筋合いか、」
すらも、

問題提起されかねません。
"

ですので、

今回は　討議内に、
含めさせて　頂いた、
次第です。
"

如何ですか、

幾ばくかでも　私は、
ご疑念、ご質問、
等へと、
アプローチできましたでしょうか？