# 意見交換努力が　抑制的な、現状に付いて。

Tags: 討議

特に、

メタの　討議タクでも、
異な、一般質問でも、

相互理解努力を　求める、
背景から　しては、
似つかわしくない、

反証も、説明も、追加質問も、説明要求も、釈明も、抗議も、異議申立も、
どんな内容でも　無関係に、
発言回数に対し　抑制的です、

直しませんか？
"

恐らくは、

過去の　経緯から、
そう　されたのでしょう。
"

ですがね、

無関係な　対象に、
其の　質を、
見もせず、

違反可能性を　根拠なく、
割り当てては、

如何な　ものでしょうか？
"

其処には、

踏み越えては　いけない、
倫理違反が、
明らかに　伺えます。
"

抑も、

任意個人に　課される、
非は、
自責起因のみで　あるのが、

健全な　民主主義運営上での、
基礎であり、大原則です。
"

しかるに、

起こるか　解らない、
不当行為を、

起こすか　断定し得ない、
ものに、

評価機械も、弁明機会も、　30日夜半　改訂：質問者
　　　　　　　　　　　　【内容、】　機械　→　機会
与えられる　未然から、

未利用未来ユーザーに対して、
実行未然犯罪罪として、
課すような　事は、

推定無罪の　原則の、
真逆です、

犯罪です。
"

他方、

失礼ながら　運用都合とは、
紐解けば、

恐らくは　十数名程度の、
都合でしかない　もの。
"

此を、

根拠として　ユーザーを、
規制するとは、

遥に　大人数の、
自由への　拘束。
"

いい変えれば、

小数都合で、
遥　多数の、
公益を　奪う、
事。
"

詰まり、

公益を　甚だしく、
逸している　行為、

公益に　資する、
範囲までは、
自由を　保障しない、
憲法にすら、

抵触し兼ねません。
"

闊達に、

皆様が　尊ぶ、
ルール通りに、

もっと　相互理解努力を、
易々　深められる、
方向に、

変えては、戻しては、
如何でしょうか？

Comment: 「恐らくは」とかいていらっしゃるのでまずはその推測事項の事実確認をしてはいかがでしょうか？「全有権者数の51%以上の人が投票した結果を有効とする」がおそらく最も民主主義に近いとは思いますが、選挙でもそのようなことをしていまうと立ち行かなくなることは目に見えてわかります。現状の全有権者数の何パーセントなのか、有効得票数の何パーセントなのか、そこから議論は開始されるべきかなと思います。

Comment: keitaro_so様、
"
ご返信　有り難うございます。
"
"
此は、
"
異な　事を、
申される。
"
"
どうやら、
"
質問文面を　理解されていない、
ご様子、
"
"
再度、
"
質問文を　確認されてから、
ご返答を　頂けますよう、
お願いつつ。
"
"
御身信頼性に、
"
触る　記載は、
直ぐに、
削除なされるよう、
お勧めして　おきます。

Comment: 抑も、
"
》不同意言論弾圧すら　違法だ、
と　いうのに、
"
"
此方でも、
"
禁止させている、
意味上不可欠な　部位にまで、
手を　及ぼす、
違反行為は、
"
特に　お辞め、
頂けませんか？
"
不謹慎　過ぎますよ？
"
"
又、

〉編集履歴は残っているので、
"
仮に、
"
モデレーターの　方ヾから、
見えようと。
"
"
少なくとも、
"
他者介入の　全てを、
私からは　漏らさず、
見る　事は、
出来ません。
"
"
詰まり、
"
示されようは　不適切、
沿いかねます。

Comment: すでに裏付けの回答が出てしまいましたが、10票にも満たないマイナス票(おそらく投票しているユニーク数は十数人)でアカウントの停止や措置は厳しく、もっと緩やかにするべきだという提案と理解していましたが、違いますか？

Comment: 私はこの質問にクローズ票を投票します 。なぜなら... 投稿内容に対する議論そのものでなく、文学的表現を目的としている様子が見られると考えられる（[編集履歴](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3560/revisions)も参照）。これはStack OverflowおよびMetaの範囲から外れると考えます。

Comment: sayuri様、

貴方にとって　情報価値とは、
内容ですか？　装丁ですか？
"
根本的な　認識を、
欠いては　折られませんか？
"
"
少し、
"
俯瞰視的に　話しますが、
今世では　分業化が、
進んで　いますよね？
"
"
尚、
"
一人で　全てを、
担う　必要が、
ありますか？
"
"
では、
"
装蹄を　整える、
ものと、
主眼点を　示す、
ものと、
何方が　高価値ですか？
"
"
仮にも、
"
もし　両方が、
揃わなければならないと、
申されるならば。
"
"
此処に、
"
有名な　話しを、
提示しましょう。
"
"
其れは、
"
ヨーロッパで　幼児が、
其の　つたなさを、
超えて、
"
堤防決壊の　予兆を、
大人に　知らしめ、
数多の　命を、
救った　話しです。
"
"
現実では、
"
此の　方は、
英雄に　湛えられ、
銅像が　建てられて、
いますが。
"
"
貴方は、
"
彼の　功績を、
其の　つたなさのみに、
固執して、
否定するのですか？
否定し得るのですか？
"
"
今一度、
"
情報価値の　真髄とは、
なんですか？
"
何か　誤解されては、
いませんか？

Comment: 〉文学的表現を目的としている様子が
"
事実背景を　超越した、
決め付けは　お止めください、
"
邪推ですよ？
抗議します。
"
"
当該文体こそが、
"
正しい　日本語の在り方です、
商業ベース記載文体が　歪まされた、
ディファクトスタンダードな　だけです。
"
"
私は、
"
正しさに　沿っているだけで、
文学的表現を　目指している、
訳では　ありません、
"
不実誹謗中傷は　ルール違反です、
お改めください。
"
貴方には　失望しましたよ。

Comment: この質問にクローズ票を投じます。やり取りを読んでいくと、どうも解決したい実際の課題が無いようです。より具体的に、解決したい特定の問題についてご質問いただけないでしょうか。そのようにすることでご質問の内容が明確になり、回答しやすくなります。

Answer (score 7):

[ストーキング誹謗行為の　可能性に付いて、](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3526/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%AA%B9%E8%AC%97%E8%A1%8C%E7%82%BA%E3%81%AE-%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E6%80%A7%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)でも感じましたが、「大人数」「小数」（少数の誤り？）という表現が気になりました。noubleさんは一部の利用者にのみにマイナス評価を受けているとお考えでしたら、誤っていますので認識を改めてください。

まず、Stack Overflowでは利用者は各投稿に対して一度しか投票できません。 -6 となっている場合は、少なくとも6人の人がマイナス投票したことを表します。

その上で、Stack Overflowでは直近１週間を除く履歴は[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)で公開されています。[noubleさんに対して行われた投票](https://data.stackexchange.com/jame/query/1403810/id-44463-nouble)として集計してみましたが、5月1日現在（4月24日以前のデータ）、

| VoteType | Count |
| --- | --- |
| DownMod | 25 |
| ModeratorReview | 6 |

となっていて、プラス投票は１つもありません。

加えて、[noubleさんの投稿に対するスコア](https://data.stackexchange.com/jame/query/1403812/id-44463-nouble)も列挙してみましたが、プラス投票しかできないコメントを含めて、一切のプラスが存在しません。

繰り返しになりますが、現在公開されている範囲で **ユーザーID 44463 noubleさんに対してプラスの評価を行っている人は一人もいません。** これが現実です。