# close理由は　何ですか？

Tags: サポート, 質問のクローズ

[excelシート関数のみでの　〜2百万以上の、1次元配列連番の　生成。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75802/excel%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae-2%e7%99%be%e4%b8%87%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%ae-1%e6%ac%a1%e5%85%83%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97%e9%80%a3%e7%95%aa%e3%81%ae-%e7%94%9f%e6%88%90)
が　closeされました。
"

回復には、

何処を　書き換えれば、
復帰しますか？
何処が　駄目なのでしょうか？
"

ご提案を、

此の　場で、
求めます。
"

但し、

内容、要点、
等に付いてのみです、

Answer (score 8):

- [周方向総応力の　求め方。 [クローズ済み]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74846/%E5%91%A8%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E7%B7%8F%E5%BF%9C%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%AE-%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E6%96%B9)
- [周方向任意点総応力に付いて、 [クローズ済み]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75562/%E5%91%A8%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E7%82%B9%E7%B7%8F%E5%BF%9C%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
- [excelシート関数のみでの　〜2百万以上の、1次元配列連番の　生成。 [クローズ済み]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75802/excel%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE-2%E7%99%BE%E4%B8%87%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE-1%E6%AC%A1%E5%85%83%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E9%80%A3%E7%95%AA%E3%81%AE-%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90)

いずれのページにも

> クローズされました。この質問は [オフトピック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) です。この質問では現在、回答を受け付けていません。
> この質問は、スタック・オーバーフローについて[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)で定義されている範囲から外れているようです。

と書かれている通りです。なぜオフトピックと判断したのかは投票者それぞれ異なりますが、私自身の考えはこのようにコメントしています。

[１つ目](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74846/%E5%91%A8%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E7%B7%8F%E5%BF%9C%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%AE-%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E6%96%B9#comment83585_74846)

> 質問されるのは問題ありません。しかし大量の改行・空行・分かち書き・読点など、ポエムのようでした。他者とコミュニケーションをとるのであれば、日本語文章の書き方について学ぶことをお勧めします。その上で、答えてほしい内容を尋ねるようにしてください。今回、質問文を適当に編集しましたが、私は専門外で全く分かりませんので、ご自身で不足部分を加筆いただけますでしょうか。

[２つ目](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74846/%E5%91%A8%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E7%B7%8F%E5%BF%9C%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%AE-%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E6%96%B9#comment83628_74846)

> 多数の追加コメントをされていますが、質問内容にほとんど触れることなく文体に固執しているように見受けられました。そうであれば、この投稿は質問ではなく、また当サイトの目的（Q&Aの蓄積）に相応しくないと判断します。

[３つ目](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3560/%E6%84%8F%E8%A6%8B%E4%BA%A4%E6%8F%9B%E5%8A%AA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%8C-%E6%8A%91%E5%88%B6%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA-%E7%8F%BE%E7%8A%B6%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6#comment3430_3560)

> 私はこの質問にクローズ票を投票します 。なぜなら... 投稿内容に対する議論そのものでなく、文学的表現を目的としている様子が見られると考えられる（編集履歴も参照）。これはStack OverflowおよびMetaの範囲から外れると考えます。

---

今回の「excelシート関数のみでの　〜2百万以上の、1次元配列連番の　生成。」においても、[nekketsuuuさんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75802/excel%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE-2%E7%99%BE%E4%B8%87%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE-1%E6%AC%A1%E5%85%83%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E9%80%A3%E7%95%AA%E3%81%AE-%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90#comment85812_75802)

> Microsoft 365 などでの Excel は 1 ワークシートでの最大行数が 1,048,576 行 となっており、それより大きな数に対して連番を作っても 1 ワークシート内の 1 列として並べることができません。

が全てでしょう。約100万行しか扱えないExcelで200万行を扱えないと言われても話になりません。スタックオーバーフローの目的であるQ&Aの蓄積においてはそれで完結しているはずです。にもかかわらず、相変わらず回答コメントに目を向けることなく、文学的な表現に固執しています。

これについては[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)の冒頭説明から引用します。

> **スタック・オーバーフロー** は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のためのQ&Aサイトです。ユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティの集まりである、Stack Exchange ネットワークの一部として運営されています。目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。

---

なお、クローズとは別に投票で -5 か -6 辺りまで下がりますと、トップページの一覧表示から外されます。これはスタックオーバーフローの独特な機能で、低品質な質問は取り扱わないというものです。閲覧者の目に留まらなくなるため、閲覧者による質問の改善は望めなくなります。質問者さんがご自身の行動を悔い改め、スタックオーバーフロー コミュニティに受け入れられるように質問文を改善する必要があります。

低品質な質問は取り扱わないことについては[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)からリンクされている[Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)で説明されています。部分的に引用しますが、全体はリンク先を確認してください。

> While we value good questions (and asking a great question is absolutely an art), we want to explicitly encourage people to provide the best possible answers. Without people interested in providing good answers, the questions are moot. We know that answers have more intrinsic…
> 良い質問を評価する一方で（素晴らしい質問をすることはまさに芸術です）、最良となり得る回答を提供する人々を明確に奨励したいと考えています。良い回答を提供しようとする人がいなければ、質問は無意味なものになってしまいます。回答が本質であることを知っています…

> That’s why we’re determined to keep question quality high, even at the cost of refusing a little sand. It’s true that you can’t have Q&A; without questions, but having the wrong sorts of questions is far more dangerous. The fastest way to kill any Q&A; site is to flood it with low-quality questions.
> 多少の砂を拒絶してでも、質問の質を高く保つことを決定しました。質問のないQ&Aはありえませんが、間違った種類の質問も非常に危険です。質の低い質問で溢れかえると、どんなQ&Aサイトも早々に潰れます。

Answer (score 8):

Close に投票したものです（クローズとしては「オフトピック」になりましたが，僕の投票は「詳細さが必要」でした）．

- 「連番は通常 `ROW(A:A)` でやるが2000000以上の連番が作れない，どうすればよいか？」なら個人的にはオントピックな質問として成立し，「→無理です」で回答になると思います．

  - ですが，その後の対応をみるにこれが求めておられるお答えではなさそうでした．
  - 一方，上記1行で要約した部分以外の記載についてはそれ自身は質問の体にはなっておらず，むしろ質問者の方の論説に近い印象を受けました．
  - このため，投稿された本文から，それに対して回答がつけられうる「質問」を取り出すには情報が不足していると考えクローズに票を投じました．
- 再オープンに僕が投票するとすれば，それは「無理です」が回答にならない理由と[質問者の具体的なニーズが詳細](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)に示され，[実際的で回答可能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) なものになったときです．ここで言う「回答可能」というのは，僕の解釈では，適切な回答が存在して，かつそれが適切であることが客観的に判断できることです
- また，有り体に申し上げて文章の読解が非常に困難です（これはこれまで複数の人間から指摘されており，客観的事実として受け止めていただく必要があります）．文全体の構成自身に問題があるの他，一般的でない（→読み手が意図を理解できない）装飾が多数行われており文面を追うだけでも努力が必要で，かつその修正を拒んでおられるということであれば，これだけを事由にして削除も検討してよいのではないかとおもいます．

  - 過去の質問へのコメントについた，文学的表現が質問の主眼と考えられためオフトピックという判断は，僕自身は採用しませんでしたが，十分妥当な考え方だと思います．